# Captions using R "tables" package with kableExtra formatting

Tags: r, formatting, caption, kableextra

I am trying to add a caption to a table output from the package "tables" in R followed by additional formatting using kableExtra.

Although other threads have found ways to add caption headers by using additional LaTeX code ([Caption not appearing for LaTeX table when knitting using Hmisc LaTeX Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526634/caption-not-appearing-for-latex-table-when-knitting-using-hmisc-latex-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Hmisc::latex not printing caption w/ tabular object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398093/hmisclatex-not-printing-caption-w-tabular-object?rq=1)), these solutions do not appear compatible with the more recent `toKable()` function which allows additional formatting with kableExtra.

Typically a caption would be added during when `kable(x, caption = "mycaption")` is used. However when it is genereated as following, an error will occur (`Error in toKable(., booktabs = T) : 'table' must be a 'tabular' object.`). It appears if I try to add any additional formatting through `latex()`, such as adding a caption, the object type will change making it unusable with the `toKable()` function. Any insight into how to use `toKable()` with additional LaTeX formatting that has been passed through `latex()` would be greatly appreciated!

```r
library(tables)
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)

 tabular((Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)* (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris) %>%
   latex(., options = list(tabular = "longtable",
                           toprule = "\\caption{Table 1. My favorite caption}\\\\\\toprule")) %>%
   toKable(., booktabs = T)
```

The LaTeX output before being passed to `toKable()`:

```
\begin{longtable}{lccccc}
\caption{Table 1. My favorite caption}\\\toprule
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Length} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Width} \\ 
Species  & n & mean & sd & mean & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sd} \\ 
\hline
setosa  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $5.01$ & $0.35$ & $3.43$ & $0.38$ \\
versicolor  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $5.94$ & $0.52$ & $2.77$ & $0.31$ \\
virginica  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $6.59$ & $0.64$ & $2.97$ & $0.32$ \\
All  & $150$ & $5.84$ & $0.83$ & $3.06$ & $0.44$ \\
\hline 
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering around a bit with the code and trying to understand how each works... I tried pasting the options list directly into `toKable`. This seemed to work and it appears `toKable` shared similar options to those of `latex()`.

```r
tabular((Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)* (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd),
        data=iris) %>%
  toKable(., booktabs = T,
          options = list(tabular = "longtable",
                                          toprule = "\\caption{My favorite caption}\\\\\\toprule"))
```

This spits out the following LaTex code correctly, as desired above:

```r
\begin{longtable}{lccccc}
\caption{Table 1. My favorite caption}\\\toprule
 &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Length} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sepal.Width} \\ \cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
Species  & n & mean & sd & mean & \multicolumn{1}{c}{sd} \\ 
\midrule
setosa  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $5.01$ & $0.35$ & $3.43$ & $0.38$ \\
versicolor  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $5.94$ & $0.52$ & $2.77$ & $0.31$ \\
virginica  & $\phantom{0}50$ & $6.59$ & $0.64$ & $2.97$ & $0.32$ \\
All  & $150$ & $5.84$ & $0.83$ & $3.06$ & $0.44$ \\
\bottomrule 
\end{longtable}
```

The LaTeX code can then be presented as needed in reports or otherwise. In a Rmarkdown document converted to PDF this can look like (remember to call the `tables` and`kableExtra` packages):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing, I was looking for exactly this. I can add the caption as above but it still appears just as normal body text and without a table reference when I render the Latex doc. SO in case useful for anyone else

What worked for me was to use the latexTable function from the vignette:

```
   tab1<-latexTable(tabular((Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2) 
      (Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd),data=iris), caption = "Iris sepal data", label = "sepals")
```

and then and just treated it as a kable object and could add headers, etc

```
    tab1  %>% add_header_above(c("Blah" = 1, "Bing" = 2, "Bong" = 2)) %>% save_kable(paste0(resultspath,"tab1.tex"), float = FALSE)
```